# write a function which takes a linked list as a parameter and returns nodes found in even positions in the original list

Tags: c

I can't get my program to work correctly. I can't get it to print the even nodes at all. I'm pretty new to linked list. I get the initial normal list to work and print, but can't even get the other function to call/work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {

int data;
 struct node* next;

}node;

struct node* head;
struct node* evenHead;

node* copyEven(node *mylist)
 {
    node* newHead = NULL;
    node* temptr = NULL;
    int count = 1;

    for(temptr = mylist;  temptr->next != NULL; temptr = temptr->next){
        if ( count % 2 == 0){
            node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
            newNode->data = temptr->data;
            if(newHead == NULL)
            {
                newHead = newNode;
            }
            for (temptr = newHead; temptr->next != NULL; temptr = temptr->next);
                node *ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                temptr->next = ptr;
                ptr->data = temptr->data;
                ptr->next = NULL;
        }
        count++;
    }
return newHead;
}

void Insert(int x)
{
node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
temp->data = x;
temp->next = head;
head = temp;
 }
void print()
 {
     node* temp = head;
    printf("List is : ");

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void printEven()
{
    node* temp = evenHead;
    printf("even list is: ");

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{

    head = NULL;
    evenHead= NULL;

    Insert(1);
    Insert(2);
    Insert(3);
    Insert(4);

    print();

    evenHead = copyEven(head);

     printEven();

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This is a pretty good effort, but it has several problems which will take some time to work through....

Comment: thanks for your input, any idea where to start or how to fix it? :( I'm pretty stumped, I don't want to continue messing around with things and end up buturing my code.

Comment: That's all right.  Let's work this through one stage at a time.  I had better post this as an *answer* below, where we can work on it.

Comment: indiv: In main, I initialize it as a global variable, and set it to null in main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} node;

node *copyEven(node *mylist){
    node *newHead = NULL, *temptr = NULL;
    int count = 1;

    while(mylist){
        if ( count % 2 == 0){
            node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
            newNode->data = mylist->data;
            newNode->next = NULL;
            if(newHead == NULL){
                temptr = newHead = newNode;
            } else {
                temptr = temptr->next = newNode;
            }
        }
        count++;
        mylist = mylist->next;
    }
    return newHead;
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what your statement: temptr = newHead = newNode is equivalent too. is that the same as saying. temptr = newHead; newHead = newNode?

Comment: @user3474281  `temptr = newHead = newNode;` is `newHead = newNode; temptr = newNode;` (Assigned from right to left). it is not same as `temptr = newHead; newHead = newNode;`

Answer (score 1):

```
void printEverySecondNode(node *in)
{
    while (in && in->next)
    {
        printf(" %d", in->next->data);
        in = in->next->next;
    }
    return;
}

node *copyReverseHalfList(node *in)
{
    node *out = NULL;
    node *cur = NULL;
    while (in && in->next)
    {
        cur = malloc(sizeof(node));
        cur->data = in->next->data;
        cur->next = out;
        in = in->next->next;
        out = cur;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you EOF, unfortunately, my problem states that my function is to return a new list :(

Comment: @user3474281: Well, you haven't specified the new list has to be in the same order as the old one, so...

Comment: my mistake, It just has to contain the even elements. but I guess that's still following the same order.

Comment: @user3474281: Well, my new function reverses the list while copying every second node. Does that satisfy your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

This answer developed stage by stage as the OP and I discussed the solution.  The OP got the answer he wanted semi-interactively with me, but I am not sure how useful the archived, non-interactive answer will be to you, if you are reading these words.  Still, here it is for archival.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

To begin:

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    node* next;
} node;

node* head;
node* evenHead;
```

The `struct node` is legal in C, but it does not work with the `typedef`.  If you will use `typedef`, then just type `node`.  But then, because the `struct node` contains a pointer that points to an object of the same type, this expansion helps:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
typedef struct node node;

node* head;
node* evenHead;
```

And you should change any other `struct node` later in your code to `node`.

With the last change, your code has an actual type called `struct node`, and an abbreviation for that type called `node`.

With these changes, the code at least compiles (on my machine).  Is yours compiling?

Comment: inside the struct, if I leave it as node* next it gives me an error: unknown type name 'node'

Comment: Okay.  Now try the second edit above, too.  We're taking this stage by stage.  Let me know when it compiles.

Comment: Yes, mine compiles and prints the first 1, 2, 3, 4 but thats the initial print, It seems my problem is with my copyeven function

Comment: What do you expect it to print, and why, and how?

Comment: It should print 2, 4. my Copyeven functions is supposed to iterate through the original head (1,2,3,4) and when it reaches an even, it makes a new node to add to the evenHead list and in the end I return the evenHead list.

Comment: Okay.  Let's read it.  I'll need a few minutes to read, so see if you cannot solve it, yourself, while I am reading.

Comment: What does this do, or what is it meant to do?  `for (temptr = newHead; temptr->next != NULL; temptr = temptr->next);`  (Nice style, by the way.)  Is it just to let `temptr` point to the list's last element?

Comment: Fair enough.  You will eventually want to improve this technique, since for a long list it would waste processor time to run through the whole list every time you added a node to it.  However, your technique is obvious and will work, so we'll go with it for now....

Comment: However, you have an outer loop and an inner loop.  Each loop is controlled by a pointer.  It looks to me as though the two loops are both controlled by the *same* pointer, `temptr`.  Is this right?  What do you think of that?...

Comment: ahhh, yes. I see. But I am unsure what shall I do to correct it, should I make a seperate pointer, pointing to temptr, and use that so I do not mess around with the outer temptr?

Comment: yes I got your number, thank you. I have class in a couple minutes. I'll try and call you after, thank you so much!!

Comment: I figured it out, but I really appreciate your effort and time you were willing to put in. Hope you have a great night!